# How to pass a variable to a gnuplot function in a script?

Tags: bash, function, variables, gnuplot

How can I pass a variable within a script to gnuplot?

I ask the user to enter grid dimensions:

```
read -p "Enter grid components (x, y, z): " -a grid
```

Then I call this function to give me a plot:

```
create_TotE_vs_Kgrid_plot(grid)
```

Where the function is defined this way:

```
create_TotE_vs_Kgrid_plot(grid) {

gnuplot <<\__EOF
    plot "TotE_vs_Kgrid_convergence_${grid[0]}a_${grid[1]}a_${grid[2]}a.txt" using 2:1 w lp ls 1    
__EOF
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work. How can I use the elements within "grid" in gnuplot?

Answer (score 1):

Arguments for functions in bash work different. To use arguments to a function, do the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
function myfunc {
    local arg1=$1
    local arg2=$2
    # arg3=$3, arg4=$4, etc

    echo $arg1 $arg2
}
myfunc "derp" "test" # output is "derp test"
exit 0
```

As example:

```
#!/bin/bash
function plot_something {
    local filename=$1
    gnuplot --persist <<-EOF
        plot "$filename" using 2:1 w lp ls 1
EOF
}
plot_something 'test.txt'
```

Content of 'test.txt'

```
# value0        value1  value2
3.141592        138     0.1
2.718281        128     1.5
1.30357         256     2.0
```